# Basic jquery how to combine current slide/fade elements and fix opacity?

Tags: jquery, css

Notice `#element2`, I have two functions but only the slide function works. I would like when you hover over it you start at 50% opacity and fade into 100%

Here's the code:

```
  $("#element2").hover(function() {
        $("#next").show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300); 
        $("#next").fadeIn(300);
    },
        function() {
            $("#next").hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300); 
        $("#next").fadeOut(300);
    });
```

Here's the code in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/pQzWp/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excellent answer here:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/combine-slide-and-fade-functions/

You should use `animate`.  In your particular case, I believe the following should work:

```
$("#next").animate({opacity: 'toggle', width: 'toggle'}, 300);
```

Comment: Very nice! One thing, how do I make my animation appear from right to left?

Comment: I'm actually looking at the same website. Code is not quite working am I missing anything? http://jsfiddle.net/pQzWp/10/

Comment: Sorry more complicated than I thought.  Working on it now.  I'll get back to you shortly.

Comment: This should do it:  http://jsfiddle.net/VivekVish/pQzWp/12/  Please tell me if you have any questions about it.  Thanks!